forcemerge runs forever on indices with vectors in elasticsearch
There is a problems with forcemerge in indices with dense_vector field inside it. Sometimes it takes to forcmerge from 15-20 segments to 5 few hours and sometime it takes more than a day, segments number is not changed.
And as far as forcmerge is not cancellable task then only one way I'd found - restart nodes (we use ECK). After restarting it begin to forcemerge once more and in most cases this helps.
Indices with dense_vector don't save vector in _source
"_source": {
        "excludes": [
          "embedding"
        ]
      },

Resources are more than needed, on indexing nodes there are enough memory, cpu, ssd disks. For Elastic half of memory is given, other - for vectors index and for linux any other IO operations.
I've made a log of forcemerge, here is one of many examples:
date                 avg_segments run_time      docs_count          size         index_nodes            task_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-04-09 23:23:05        14.4   24.7m       7,806,633 docs       191.71 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-09 23:30:01        14.4   31.6m       7,806,633 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-09 23:37:19        14.4   38.9m       7,806,633 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-09 23:44:34        14.4   46.2m       7,806,633 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-09 23:51:42        15.4   53.3m       7,806,654 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-09 23:58:51        15.4      1h       7,806,654 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:06:02        16.4    1.1h       7,806,698 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:13:10        16.4    1.2h       7,806,698 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:20:21        17.0    1.3h       7,806,702 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:27:32        17.0    1.4h       7,806,702 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:34:43        17.8    1.6h       7,806,710 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:41:53        17.8    1.7h       7,806,710 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:49:01        18.6    1.8h       7,806,791 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 00:56:14        18.8    1.9h       7,806,791 docs       191.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:03:29        19.8      2h       7,806,927 docs       191.77 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:10:45        19.8    2.2h       7,806,927 docs       191.77 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:17:57        20.7    2.3h       7,810,639 docs       191.97 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:25:09        20.8    2.4h       7,810,639 docs       191.97 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:32:30        21.8    2.5h       7,813,686 docs       192.18 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:39:41        21.8    2.6h       7,813,686 docs       192.18 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:46:55        22.7    2.8h       7,818,686 docs       192.37 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 01:53:52        22.8    2.9h       7,818,686 docs       192.38 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:00:51        23.5      3h       7,820,273 docs       192.44 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:07:49        23.8    3.1h       7,820,273 docs       192.44 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:14:43        23.8    3.2h       7,820,273 docs       192.44 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:21:38        24.8    3.3h       7,825,273 docs       192.65 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:28:38        24.8    3.5h       7,825,273 docs       192.65 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:35:33        25.8    3.6h       7,830,273 docs       192.85 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:42:31        25.8    3.7h       7,830,273 docs       192.85 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:49:29        26.8    3.8h       7,835,273 docs       193.05 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 02:56:23        26.8    3.9h       7,835,273 docs       193.05 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:03:24        26.8      4h       7,835,273 docs       193.05 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:10:24        26.8    4.2h       7,835,273 docs       193.05 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:17:21        28.8    4.3h       7,835,504 docs       193.06 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:24:26        28.8    4.4h       7,835,504 docs       193.06 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:31:24        29.3    4.5h       7,840,504 docs       193.24 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:38:21        29.8    4.6h       7,840,504 docs       193.26 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:45:23        29.8    4.7h       7,840,504 docs       193.29 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:52:22        30.8    4.9h       7,845,504 docs       193.47 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 03:59:18        30.8      5h       7,845,504 docs       193.47 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:06:17        31.8    5.1h       7,850,504 docs       193.67 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:13:13        31.8    5.2h       7,850,504 docs       193.67 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:20:07        32.8    5.3h       7,850,569 docs       193.67 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:27:03        32.8    5.4h       7,850,569 docs       193.67 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:34:00        33.8    5.5h       7,850,661 docs       193.72 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:40:54        32.9    5.7h       7,850,661 docs       193.52 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:47:52        33.9    5.8h       7,855,661 docs       193.72 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 04:54:49        33.9    5.9h       7,855,661 docs       193.72 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:01:51        33.9      6h       7,855,661 docs       193.72 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:08:55        33.9    6.1h       7,855,661 docs       193.72 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:15:52        34.4    6.2h       7,861,114 docs       193.98 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:22:40        37.3    6.4h       7,862,614 docs       193.98 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:29:28        37.3    6.5h       7,862,614 docs       193.98 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:36:10        38.3    6.6h       7,862,629 docs       193.98 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:42:49        38.3    6.7h       7,862,629 docs       193.98 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:49:28        39.3    6.8h       7,867,629 docs       194.18 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 05:56:06        39.3    6.9h       7,867,629 docs       194.18 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:02:45        40.3      7h       7,868,001 docs       194.20 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:09:22        40.3    7.1h       7,868,001 docs       194.20 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:16:05        40.4    7.2h       7,868,059 docs       194.20 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:22:43        40.4    7.4h       7,868,059 docs       194.20 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:29:24        40.4    7.5h       7,868,059 docs       194.20 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:36:04        41.4    7.6h       7,873,059 docs       194.40 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:42:44        41.4    7.7h       7,873,059 docs       194.40 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:49:22        42.4    7.8h       7,878,059 docs       194.60 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 06:56:03        42.4    7.9h       7,878,059 docs       194.60 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:02:53        42.4      8h       7,878,059 docs       194.60 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:09:39        42.4    8.1h       7,878,059 docs       194.60 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:16:25        41.6    8.3h       7,883,059 docs       194.81 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:23:14        41.0    8.4h       7,883,809 docs       194.97 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:30:02        41.0    8.5h       7,883,809 docs       194.97 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:36:46        40.2    8.6h       7,888,809 docs       195.15 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:43:27        40.2    8.7h       7,888,809 docs       195.15 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:50:06        41.0    8.8h       7,888,813 docs       195.15 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 07:56:45        41.0    8.9h       7,888,813 docs       195.15 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:03:27        42.0      9h       7,893,813 docs       195.35 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:10:08        42.0    9.1h       7,893,813 docs       195.35 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:16:52        41.2    9.3h       7,898,813 docs       195.56 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:23:39        41.2    9.4h       7,898,813 docs       195.53 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:30:18        41.2    9.5h       7,898,813 docs       195.53 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:36:59        42.2    9.6h       7,903,063 docs       195.73 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:43:40        42.2    9.7h       7,903,063 docs       195.73 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:50:23        42.3    9.8h       7,903,216 docs       195.74 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 08:57:04        42.3    9.9h       7,903,216 docs       195.73 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:03:42        42.3     10h       7,903,216 docs       195.73 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:10:22        42.3   10.2h       7,903,216 docs       195.73 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:17:13        42.9   10.3h       7,913,216 docs       196.41 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:23:53        41.1   10.4h       7,913,216 docs       195.76 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:30:33        41.1   10.5h       7,913,216 docs       195.77 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:37:10        41.2   10.6h       7,915,130 docs       195.83 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:43:47        41.2   10.7h       7,915,130 docs       195.83 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:50:28        41.3   10.8h       7,920,130 docs       196.03 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 09:57:05        41.3   10.9h       7,920,130 docs       196.02 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:03:44        41.4     11h       7,925,130 docs       196.27 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:10:23        41.4   11.2h       7,925,130 docs       196.09 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:17:02        42.4   11.3h       7,930,130 docs       196.37 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:23:40        41.5   11.4h       7,930,130 docs       196.13 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:30:15        41.5   11.5h       7,930,130 docs       196.13 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:36:55        42.5   11.6h       7,930,169 docs       196.13 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 10:43:34        42.5   11.7h       7,930,169 docs       196.13 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 18:07:32        40.4   19.1h       8,028,482 docs       196.69 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]
2024-04-10 18:11:41        40.4   19.2h       8,028,482 docs       196.69 GB    indexing-0,indexing-1   KEFbgZcMQUyb1K4wZGs4Ew:27295972 maxSegments[1]

More details are here

Quick question: it's not clear from the context (even in discuss), but are indexing operations still ongoing while force merge is running on the index?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
